# Finding $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ with constant term inside.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I have a bit of confusion regarding how to find $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$.

Let's say the expected value of $X$, $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is $= 10 + 5p$.

Would $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ just be $= 10 + 25p$?

Why I feel this doesn't make sense is that, assuming there was no constant term, the $$\operatorname{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2 = 25p - (5p)^2 = 25p - 25p^2 = 25p(1 - p).$$ Adding a constant shouldn't change this variance.

However, with the constant $10$ term, we get $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2 = (10 + 25p) - (10 + 5p)^2 = (10 + 25p) - (100 + 100p + 25p^2) = -25p^2 - 75p - 90,$$ which is different.

Is my calculation for $E[X^2]$ wrong? Or do you just ignore the constant term entirely, and find the variance from there?

EDIT:

I should add more about the random variable $X$.

$X$ increases its value by $5$ with probability $p$, and has no change with probability $(1-p)$, and always has a constant $10$ term. So $E[X] = 10 + 5p$.

Answer (score 2):

Guide to compute $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$:

$$X=10+5Y$$ where $Y \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$

$$\operatorname{Var}(X)=\operatorname{Var}(10+5Y)=25\operatorname{Var}(Y)$$

Can you evaluate $\operatorname{Var}(X)$? and from there recover $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$?

Alternatively:

$$X^2=(10+5Y)^2=100+100Y+25Y^2$$

and then you can take the expectation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real easy way to compute $\mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right]$ given $\mathbb{E}[X]$. You can use
$$
\mathrm{Var}\ X = \mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right] - \left(\mathbb{E}[X]\right)^2,
$$
so given the expected value and variance you can find the second moment, or given the expected value and the second moment, you can find the variance.

However, if you only have the expected value, since variance is non-negative, you must have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right] \ge \left(\mathbb{E}[X]\right)^2
$$
which at least gives you a lower bound...